# check if words against a dictionary. words are still in dictionary if can be created by dropping 1 character from a dictionary word

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to code the following question in Python

If I have a dictionary [apple, hello, world]

and a list of words [apl, apple, helllo, helo, heo]

I want to return booleans indicating whether what word is 'in' the dictionary
We define a word as being in a dictionary by: it can be created from dropping a single character from any of the word in the dictionary or it is in the dictionary

```
dictionary: [apple, hello, world]
words: [apl, apple, helllo, helo, heo]

output: [False, True, False, True, False]
```

what is the best way to implement the dictionary? (aka, how to add into dictionary, and how to check if a word exists?)

extension: if we change the requirement for a word to be in the dictionary to "being one character away from any of the string in the dictionary" how can I implement that?

One character away would be: insert, remove, or replace

```
eg
dictionary: [apple, hello, world] 
words: [apble, aple, bello, worldd, worldaa, ale, helab]

outputs: [True, True, True, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

dictionary= ["apple", "hello", "world"]

words= ["apl", "apple", "helllo", "helo", "heo"]

existing_words=[]

new_word=" "

for i in range (len(dictionary)):

```
if dictionary[i] in words:

    existing_words.append(dictionary[i])

for j in range (len(dictionary[i])):

    temp=list(dictionary[i])

    del temp[j]

    new_word=''.join(temp)

    if new_word in words:

        existing_words.append(new_word)
```

print(list(set(existing_words)))

Comment: i m also new so it might be quiet messy but  i managed to return a list with all the words that exist in the dictionary (the 'extension' conditions were not solved in this one.